# Javascript object's property is defined but comes back undefined when I try to use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am completely baffled at this.  I have an object returned via a jquery ajax call.  I can look at the object itself and its properties are clearly defined.  When I try to actually access those properties, it comes back undefined.  For example:

```
console.log("data: " + data + ", data['ID']: " + data['ID']);
```

Prints this in the console:

```
data: {"ID":"2"}, data['ID']: undefined
```

What in the world could cause this?

EDIT:

Just because a lot of people asked, it does the same thing with data.ID.  So this:

```
console.log("data: " + data + ", data.ID: " + data.ID);
```

Is printing out this:

```
data: {"ID":"2"}, data.ID: undefined
```

Comment: data.ID, data is an object not an array.

Comment: what does data.ID do?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  data.ID makes no difference.  As far as I know, the two styles of syntax are the same in Javascript.

Comment: You are correct, there isn't a difference.

Comment: if you run "console.log({ID: 2}['ID']);" in the chrome javascript console, you get two logs, 2 and undefined...

Comment: Maybe you data is a string, try to `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: how do you define your id of data?

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/bL883/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If data would have been an object than you would have seen [object Object] but you do see a string, your response is just a plain text, so you need to parse it first to become a javascript object.

With jQuery you can do it this way:

```
var dataAsObj = $.parseJSON(data)
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!  That was the problem!  I didn't put "json" as the last parameter of my ajax call.  The weird thing is this isn't supposed to matter since jquery defaults to an intelligent guess according to what the return data looks like if you don't provide that last variable.  Apparently my data looked like a string for some reason!  I added "json" to the end and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your data is a string, that's why this is happening.

Try this:  `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: You too are brilliant!  Dawid was first though so I gave him the best answer.  Thanks for your help!